# How can I transition from a cardview to a dialog fragment?

Tags: android, android-transitions, cardview

I am trying to create an animation transition from a cardview to a dialog fragment. The goal is for the cardview to "grow" into the full dialog fragment.

I have experimented with shared element -- however -- because we are using ft.add instead of ft.replace (here ft is fragment transaction), this does not work.

I have also tried scaling and other things, which haven't worked either.

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: did you fished this thing?

Comment: You may try using activity with Dialog theme instead of dialog fragment.